# generated signed .apk in android studio shows error Unfortunately close

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

I am going to generate signed apk from **android studio** and i am trying to decrease .apk file size.So from somewhere i got solution to use Progaurd and for that i have to make change in **build.gradle** file.
The change is the make **"minifyEnabled true"** instead of **"minifyEnabled false"**.
here is build.gradle file code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

1android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rahu.createsomething"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Now the Question is When i Make "minifyEnabled true" i decrease my file size for 1.47 GB to 0.97 MB.
But when i run that apk file it shows error message "Unfortunately Close application".

And when generate apk with the "minifyEnable false" then it generate 1.47 GB .apk file and it works fine.
But i want 0.97 MB apk so how can i generate it?

here is my error logcat message

```
07-08 23:18:21.983  29845-29845/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.bf.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.as.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.q.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.b.a.p.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.i.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.af.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.q.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.abc.android.publish.q.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.rahu.createsomething.CreateSomething.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What error you got in your logcat? Class not found exception?

Comment: i have update my question with error log

Comment: You can try to keep the com.abc.** in your proguard rule

Answer (score 2):

Can you put detailed stack trace...I guess the issue is due to proguard optimization.

Sometimes if you use external library/jars proguard causes issues.

Also if you are calling code (the classes referenced in the code are not referenced anywhere else) through reflection and that particular class has been removed by the proguard tool,you might face an exception at runtime.

There are various ways of configuring proguard-http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring

Comment: so how can fix this??any detailed reference tutorial with example.

Comment: progaurd.cfg is default file or we have to make it?

Comment: There is   proguard-rules file located  in your project folder..you can edit it